# How can I connect java class with already running daemon

Tags: java

I have created a java application that frequently gathers data from a source and saves it to an sql database. I am also developing another application to operate on the data that is being saved to the database.

My problem is that I will be continuously modifying the operating classes but want to leave the gathering application up all the time so as not to miss any data, but the operating class needs to connect to the gathering class, and I am not sure exactly what the best way to do this is.

If possible I want the two as well connected as possible, just as if one was constructed by the other. What is the best way to do this in java? I am looking into RPC but not sure if it will be as fast as the above scenario.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: JMX- https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/what_is_jmx?

Comment: Off the top of my head I can think of two ways to achieve this. You can achieve this in a single application by loading the operating classes from external files, when they change, using class loaders. Another approach would be to use rpc like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an OSGi container like karaf you can update jars used in a running program. It has a web interface and command line interface to help you do that.

Another option is to have two programs where one talks to the other.  This way you can restart one with a new version of code without stopping the other.

Comment: Thanks for that Peter, Karaf looks good. Regarding the second option, are you referring to communication via rpc? What other ways can a newly started class interact with an already running one?